# Load strongly typed partial view several times within the same 'main' view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am working with a strongly typed partial view that renders a search form for flights. I have a main view in which I have several tabs, one tab per flight segments in the itinerary, so If the itinerary has 3 flights, A to B, B to C and C to D, I want to render 3 tabs, containing each one of those the flight search form.
How can I accomplish that keeping in mind that there is a limitation when working with strongly typed views that is that the id's and names are autogenerated, and the fact that you repeat the form 3 times in the main view gets only one rendered because of the dupes.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the simplest solution would be to pass an IEnumerable model to the strongly typed master page. Then for each the list as follows and pass in the inner class:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Partial("ViewPageName", item)
}
```

I can't see any issue with this solution. This wouldn't even require any extra controller logic.